# FIXED! Redmine: Having old application.js file included after clearing all caches

Tags: jquery, caching, nginx, redmine, thin

I upgraded Redmine from 2.3 to 2.6.
All worked clean but the filters are not working and FireBug throws me the message:

```
TypeError: $(...).live is not a function:
$('#filters-table td.field input[type=checkbox]').live('click',function() {
```

The jQuery method live() isn't used any more and the old application.js of 2.3 is loaded.
When looking into the file in the Redmine folder, there is the new application.js with working code, but the old one is loaded (out of a cache imho).

What I've done:

- Flushed the caches of Redmine multiple times
- Restarted thin client multiple times
- Even restarted the whole server
- Modified the current application.js to force a new loading

How the system is built:

- Debian Wheezy
- Nginx
- RVM

> Environment:
>   Redmine version                2.6.0.stable
>   Ruby version                   1.9.3-p429 (2013-05-15) [x86_64-linux]
>   Rails version                  3.2.19
>   Environment                    production
>   Database adapter               Mysql2

Can someone help me finding this issue?

Comment: try to recompile assets. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Didn't work. Default config for redmine does not use the "assets" folder.

Comment: **FIXED!** In the nginx config the path to the doc root was to the old one. Silly me. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a wrong doc root path in the webserver configuration. So, no problem with redmine.